# Rendering a RatingBar within an InfoWindow on Lollipop

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, infowindow

I have a RatingBar in a layout that is rendered inside an InfoWindow.

On KitKat and below, it renders fine.

[image: 4.4.4 - Nexus 7]

On Lollipop, the InfoWindow renders with an empty space for the RatingBar:

[image: 5.0.1 - Nexus 4]

Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infowindow_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Venue Name Some More Text This Should Wrap Properly"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

   <TextView
    android:id="@+id/infowindow_type"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infowindow_name"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="Type - Cuisine"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:textSize="15sp" />



<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/infowindow_rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infowindow_type"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.75" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/infowindow_norating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infowindow_rating"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:text="@string/infowindow_no_rating_yet"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
```

Any ideas to work around the issue? I assume this is down to the way that the InfoWindow renders as a static representation of the view, and something has changed in Lollipop.

[Android Bug Issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=99502&thanks=99502&ts=1421595076)

Comment: I suspect the rating bar is ok, but the stars are painted white. Could you try adding a `android:colorAccent` to your theme (the prefix is important)? It maybe some other color parameter, I'm not sure.

Comment: I don't think so - I've just tried messing with those params (using appcompat, so only seems to pick up the un-prefixed values) - other elements got the correct tints, and the ratingbar shows up when not in the InfoWindow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a workaround to this - you need to explicitly set the style on the RatingBar to ratingBarStyleIndicator:

```
    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/infowindow_rating"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/infowindow_type"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:rating="3.75"
    android:isIndicator="true"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleIndicator"
    />
```

I'm assuming that some of the RatingBar initialisation is bypassed in Lollipop when it is rendered using Canvas.Draw [Custom InfoWindows](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/infowindows#custom_info_windows)

I await the outcome of the bug report with interest.